# oh-my-zsh disable lib history.zsh

Tags: oh-my-zsh

Im using **oh-my-zsh** and there is a feature that is really annoying me. The history is share for each console. I want to disable that and after a review i found that

> .oh-my-zsh/lib/history.zsh

has this:

> setopt share_history # share command history data

How should I disable this? I mean, what is the RIGHT way. It is a lib not a plugin, if I edit the file I will not get updates for it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This question is old but anyway:

As you can use `setopt` for setting options, you can use `unsetopt` to unset them.

Just add

```
unsetopt share_history
```

after having sourced `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

(and yes, it's *really* annoying ;) )

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, what is the RIGHT way. It is a lib not a plugin, if I edit the file I will not get updates for it.

The accepted answer is the easiest way, but it bears mentioning that oh-my-zsh lets you override any file or plugin you want by putting it in `$ZSH_CUSTOM` - even stuff in lib. If you want to do more than just `unsetopt share_history` you could run this:

```
# $ZSH_CUSTOM should already be automatically set to $ZSH/custom
# but you can customize the location in your ~.zshrc.
# ie: export ZSH_CUSTOM=~/.zsh_custom

# set up lib in omz custom area
mkdir -p $ZSH_CUSTOM/lib

# start off with omz version of the file
cp $ZSH/lib/history.zsh $ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/history.zsh

# edit that file and make it what you want
${EDITOR:-vim} $ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/history.zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override an internal lib of oh-my-zsh completely,
there is a wiki entry for it: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-internals

Basically you would put an empty file at `$ZSH_CUSTOM/lib/history.zsh` to disable that lib.